# how to extract contents from flv file using any web crawler?

Tags: parsing, flv, web-crawler, nutch

My requirement is to extract text and audio from a flv file. please suggest me how can i achieve this using any web crawler. if it is not possible with web crawler please suggest me any other tool.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Nutch you can parse and extract metadata from the FLV file.
If the text has been added into the file as part of the metadata you can retrieve it with Nutch and put it into a database.

But you probably should be looking at a combination of wget (to download the content) + "a FLV stream extraction tool" to achieve what you require.

[Nutch](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch)

[Wget](http://lifehacker.com/5086682/winwget-makes-automated-downloads-a-breeze)

[FLV metadata](http://www.buraks.com/flvmdv/)

Comment: Thanks for tha reply but i hava a doubt cant we get the text from an flv file if it contains any text.... please suggest me if not suggest me any other tool which does this

Comment: If by text you mean "hard text" as part of the frame bitmap, then no; that would require some sort of OCR functionality.